# DRY issue with useRef() Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently struggling with a DRY & useRef combination in my React 16.9 project.

**My Function**

```
const rangeSlider = useRef();
const rangeBullet = useRef();

window.addEventListener("input", showSliderValue, false);

function showSliderValue() {
  const bulletPosition = (rangeSlider.current.value /rangeSlider.current.max);
  rangeBullet.current.style.left = ((bulletPosition*1.15)  * 270)  + "px";
}
```

**Ref Usage**

```
<div>
  <p ref={rangeBullet}>100</p>
  <input type="range" ref={rangeSlider} min="0.3" max="3" step="0.01"  value={cartObject.tableWidth} onChange={e => setCartObject({...cartObject, tableWidth: e.target.value})} />        
</div>
<hr/>
```

My Issue is that i now need another 5 input fields with the same functionality.
Since useRef must be unique, i have currently solved this issue by repeating the function 5 times. Is there a more smooth way of approaching this issue?

All suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating you own "RangeInput" component and hide all those ref implementations in it. 
Just don't forget to unsubscribe from those events on component unmount.

You might also consider not using `window.addEventListener` and refs at all, but rather use [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) pattern and calculate your style based on range value.